# How to make Gallery to NOT to search photos in some folders?

Tags: photos, gallery

I have many photos in many folders, but most of them are for work. I don't want Android Gallery to show those pictures when I start the app. Gallery shows 1000+ folders, but only 2 of them are pictures that I want to see. How to make Gallery not to show/search other folders?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename the folders with dot in front. Eg: newfolder to `.newfolder` and restart the phone.

Answer (score 3):

Place in every directory, you want to be excluded by the media scanner, an empty file named ".nomedia". Then restart your phone and the 'marked' directories should not be indexed any more.